# Case statement not working properly in C. Just repeating menu choices

Tags: c, case, break

I have this problem I'm working on, and I can't seem to get the case options working, every time I select 1 or 2 it just shows the menu again, even 3 or 4 for that matter, lol.

I want to be able to break off to the case statement 1 or 2 when I choose that from the menu.

thanks.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main (int argc, char ** argv)
{
    int flag = 1;
    while (flag)
    {
        //Print menu
        printf("1: Say hello\n");
        printf("2: Say goodbye\n");
        printf("0: exit\n");
        printf("Enter choice :");
        //read input
        char buffer[10];
        fgets(buffer, 10, stdin);
        //convert to number
        int number = atoi (buffer);

        //work on input
        switch (number)
        {
            case 1:
                printf("hello world\n");
                break;
            case 2:
                printf("goodbye world\n");
                break;
            case 0:
                printf("Exiting...\n");
                flag = 0;
                break;
            default:
                printf("INVAID INPUT\n");
                break;
        }
    }   
    return 0;
}
```

**SOLVED

The issue was I couldn't see the message coming back up, temporary blindness. 
So it was working perfect after all.

Comment: You mean, that if you input `1` and press enter, then the `hello world` string does not output? Does the `INVAID INPUT` shows when you enter `3` or `4`? What does it mean "to break off to the case statement"?

Comment: Inside a `switch` statement, `break` breaks *from the switch*.  It does not break from any enclosing loop.  You can use `goto` for that -- a *bona fide* useful purpose for that much-maligned statement -- or in your particular case it looks like you can set the `flag` variable to 0 so as to avoid performing another loop iteration.

Comment: Why do you expect the menu should *not* appear again? You're in a while-loop without altering the loop variable.

Comment: Actually it does work, i was blind to seeing the message coming up, lol thanks for the heads up.

Answer (score 0):

There was no issue, this is a working example of a SWITCH CASE statement.